# What adjectives do you use for someone who is constantly striving for glory and loves to be admired?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

What adjectives do you use for someone who is constantly striving for glory and loves to be admired? In Russian we use the adjective *тщеславный* for this. It translates as *vain* or *conceited* in English. But those word aren't defined as someone who loves to be admired by others and as someone who is always striving for glory.

Comment: Hmmm, I can't think of a single word that fits both meanings. Have you tried "ambitious" and "narcissist"? Do they apply in your case?

Comment: Not, really. What about words that fit one meaning?

Comment: Perhaps *vainglorious*? https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/vainglorious . q.v. "glory hog" -- two words, and colloquial, though.

Comment: No, it doesn't fit the description. It says "vainglorious" is someone who is overly proud of one's achievments. I would like to what adjective you use for someone who loves to be admired or loved for what they did.

Comment: How about "show boat"? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling that there isn't one single word that describes (1) *"someone who is constantly striving for glory"* and (2) *"someone who loves to be admired or loved for what they did"* at the same time.

My answer gives you relevant terms which *can* be made to work depending on the context and how you phrase the sentence.

For the first one, you can use

> (a) [Ambitious](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ambitious) (adj): having a strong wish to be successful, powerful, or rich (Cambridge)

Here are some suggestions for the second one:

> From Cambridge,
>
> (b) [Ostentatious](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ostentatious) (adj): too obviously showing your money, possessions, or power, in an attempt to make other people notice and admire you; intended to attract admiration or notice
>
> (c) [Flamboyant](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/flamboyant?topic=attention-seeking-distracting-and-showing-off) (adj): very confident in your behaviour, and liking to be noticed by other people, for example because of the way you dress, talk, etc; intended to be noticed, esp. by being brightly colored.
>
> - [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/flamboyant): (of a person or their behaviour) tending to attract attention because of their exuberance, confidence, and stylishness.
>
> (d) [Narcissist](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/narcissist) (n): someone who has too much admiration for himself or herself
>
> - [Seeking constant admiration, praise and approval.](http://changingminds.org/explanations/personality/disorders/narcissistic_personality.htm)
>
> (e) [Needy](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/needy) (adj): wanting too much attention and love
>
> (f) [Grandstander](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grandstander?topic=attention-seeking-distracting-and-showing-off) (n): someone who acts or speaks in a way that is intended to attract attention and impress people watching
>
> - [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/grandstander): a person whose words or actions are motivated primarily by the desire to attract attention or gain approval

This EL&U post [Word for someone who always seeks appreciation for his deeds or work](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/369248/word-for-someone-who-always-seeks-appreciation-for-his-deeds-or-work) has some interesting terms/phrases. Here is a quick list:

> compliment seeker, compliment whore, fishing for compliments, approval junkie, approbation lust